# execute npm-task on every node-dev restart

Tags: node.js, npm-scripts, node-dev

I currently have a dev-setup with node-dev and iIrecently integrated [tsoa](https://github.com/lukeautry/tsoa) into the setup to generate a swagger file and the express-routes for my app.

I already added all the necessary steps to generate my routes but right now its a manual process inside the dev-setup because I cant execute the needed npm-task on every restart of the application through node-dev.

So my question is, if its possible to start this task on every restart initiated by node-dev?

I hope someone can help me, and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your script to start your dev server, and what is the task that you want to run?

Comment: I start my dev-server with "node-dev -r tsc/register app.ts" and i want to execute "tsoa routes" for every app-restart initiated by node-dev.

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` add the following entry to `scripts`

```
"profit": "tsoa routes && node-dev -r tsc/register app.ts"
```

Then run it with

```
npm run profit
```

You can change `profit` to whatever you want

Comment: Thats not what i wanted. This would execute the first command one time but i need it to be executed everytime node-dev restarts the application(so everytime a file inside the project changes). Thx for your effort nonetheless